# Disabling push notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios8

I want to remove Push Notification from my app and I've removed all the code to register push notifications and also in the provisioning profile as well. I've re-downloaded the profile too. But, it's still prompting the alert box when launching the application after installing.

Did anyone face this issue before? You guys have any idea how to fix this issue?

This issue is not happening in iOS 7. Only in iOS 8.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about the cause. 1. Revoke APP-ID for push notification. 2. Remove all the delegate methods. 3. Remove any code that is registering for push notification. May work.

Comment: I've already done all of that. It was because I was still using Xcode 5. Problem solved in Xcode 6.